# failed to import keras with CNN model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPool2D
from keras.layers.core import Activation, Flatten, Dropout, Dense
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
import keras
```

the code can't read convolution, Batchnormaliztion, maxpool2D and etc.

I got this error:

```
No module named 'module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph''
```

Comment: can you post full error traceback?

Comment: The problem is probably that you are using TensorFlow 2.x with a version of Keras that does not support TensorFlow 2.x. Also do not mix imports between keras and tf.keras

Answer (score 0):

If the error `No module named 'module 'tensorflow'` most probably you need to install it correctly.

If the error is `module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'`:
first you need to unify the imports either use `keras` or `tensorflow.keras`

If the problem still exists try `from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as k`

Answer (score 0):

I use tensorflow version 2.2.0. And it works, but instead:

```
 from keras.layers import MaxPool2D
```

I use:

```
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you might have a problem with your Tensorflow module.
Run the following code and see if it outputs you details about your Tensorflow Module:

```
pip show tensorflow
```

If this shows you details about your TensorFlow module, then you have installed it correctly.

I would suggest you use Anaconda for module management.